# Ubuntu 12.04 installation problems

Tags: system-installation

I am new with Ubuntu, and i am trying to install it on my old PC.

Just after the "Verifying the installation configuration" prompt, i get the "No root file system--No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu" error. i need help.

Comment: are you able to run Gparted from either the installation you've just done, or from the Live CD? Either way, get it running, take a screenshot by pressing 'print screen', and post it up here as an attachment. I think it will be quite easy to fix.

Comment: I installed it by using the windows installer.

Comment: So please take a screenshot from when the error message is shown. As you are still in Windows, this should be no problem

Answer (score 2):

After allocating the disk space select the mount point as root. refer to the screenshot.

[image: ubuntu]