# during final part installation I get the message ' root' not defined go to partioning. Where can I find partioning?

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 12.04 installation problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133245/ubuntu-12-04-installation-problems)

When nstalling ubuntu I get the message ' root not found' go to partioning (menu). How do i get to partioning menu?

Comment: Are you getting this error after installation is complete, or in the middle of installation? When the installer asks about how you want to install (e.g. entire partition, dual boot, etc) what are you selecting?

Comment: I have seen this exact message a couple of hours ago: you MUST install at least one partition and mount it as root (/)

Answer (score 0):

Press the super-key (the Windows key) and in the search box type 'Gparted'. This is the partitioning tool. If it doesn't show up, then you need to install it from the Ubuntu Software Centre. Come back to us when you have Gparted working. The fix is easy from there. Good Luck. Update: there is some more help here, with a screenshot too (@Srinivas Gowda). If you want more help just ask again.  [Ubuntu 12.04 installation problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133245/ubuntu-12-04-installation-problems)